# Removing undefined string from output

Tags: javascript, undefined, output

```
console.log(index + ",\"" + array+ "\"");
```

This produces:

```
Name    "Tree"
Name    "Undefined"
Name    "park"
```

How can I have an output for

```
Name    "Tree"
Name    
Name    "park"
```

where if the array variable is undefined then not print it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function for logging.

```
function logValue(index, value) {
    var val = ('"' + value + '"') || "";

    index = '"' + index + '"';

    console.log(index + " " + val);
}
```

Then use it like so.

```
logValue(index, array);
```

Comment: This worked! But I need quotation marks around my output so I used this print statement  console.log(index + ",\"" + val+ "\""); which outputted "" for my empty ones, is there a way to keep the "" for the ones that have a value and have nothing for the ones with no value

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<array.length; i += 1){    
    if(typeof array[i] !== "undefined"){
        console.log(i + " " + Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your array probably contains names or not so...

no need to write functions for this simple check.

```
console.log(index+(array?' "'+array+'"':''));
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/3znzY/